# Qual é o nome dado para a quantidade de colunas em uma tabela?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, terminologia

Qual é o nome dado para a quantidade de colunas em uma tabela?

E o nome para a quantidade de linhas?

Comment: Coluna é considerado atributo e linha é considerado registro.

Comment: Depende @Everson existem modelagens onde cada **linha** pode ser considerado um atributo :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A quantidade de colunas é a [**aridade**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity) e a quantidade de linhas é a [**cardinalidade**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality).

[Fonte](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Relational_Database_Design/Basic_Concepts#Arity).

**Coluna**, termo muito usado em SQL, é conhecida popularmente como campo e academicamente como atributo.

**Linha**, termo muito usado em SQL, é popularmente conhecida como registro e academicamente como tupla.

Algumas fontes dão definições um pouco mais específicas para cada um.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Para contribuir um pouco, nesse [Livro](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=COUJpkH5v38C&lpg=PA52&ots=0W74PiU3Xu&dq=quantidade%20de%20colunas%20%C3%A9%20a%20aridade&hl=pt-BR&pg=PA52#v=onepage&q&f=false) na página 52 fala um pouco sobre isso.

Comment: @Everson ótimo, fica o crédito para você.

Comment: Apesar de eu também chamar assim, acho que deve-se tomar cuidado com essa nomenclatura por causa de modelagens iguais a essa: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lE3I.png.
Onde cada linha se torna um atributo de um mesmo registro.